# gridview not highlight search term

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I set up a gridview to display search results on a webpage.

I have the code below that is "supposed" to replace any instance of a search term, with a bolded version of that word.

I've tried many different versions, but nothing is working.

```
    Private Sub gvSearchResults_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvSearchResults.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            If cell.Text.Contains(searchTerm) Then
                cell.Text = cell.Text.Replace(Session("SearchTerm"), "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>" & Session("SearchTerm") & "</span>")
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there anything missing in my logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you run a debug to verify that cell.Text isn't empty? A lot of times gridviews will put text of this nature into a literal control.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks...I just did.  For some reason all my cell.text are blank...even though they are all full of text on the web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Cell.Text` is blank, then likely the gridview is placing a Literal control in the `Cell.Controls` collection. You should put something like this in:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
        If cell.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            Dim ltl as Literal = CType(cell.Controls(0), Literal)
            If ltl.Text.Contains(searchTerm) Then
                cell.Text = cell.Text.Replace(Session("SearchTerm"), "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>" & Session("SearchTerm") & "</span>")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: the ltl.Text is also empty...but I see the results in my gridview on the page...When I look at a cell in Chrome dev tools, the HTML looks like this: <td><span id="bodyContent_gvSearchResults_lblTitle_80">Cardiac</span></td>

Comment: @999cm999: Yah, I've seen that before. It means there are multiple controls in the collection. You should try 1 and 2 as well just to see where it's going.

Comment: @999cm999: Sorry, I meant the control indexes. `cell.Controls(1)` and `cell.Controls(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dubious `searchTerm` variable in your code.

Observe that in your code you are using a `searchTerm` variable ***as well as*** `Session("SearchTerm")`.

I would instead do this:

```
searchTerm = Session("SearchTerm")

If cell.Text.Contains(searchTerm) Then
     cell.Text = cell.Text.Replace(searchTerm , "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>" & searchTerm  & "</span>")
End If
```

Comment: yeah I tried that...I put the variable in there hoping that would help

Comment: Then, have you run a debug as Joel has suggested in the comments?  Have you verified that cell.Text contains a value?  Does your breakpoint make it to the `cell.Text =` code?

Comment: I put in some breakpoints and it appears as the cell.Text is always empty...which doesn't make sense because I am seeing all the results on my page